# Empty space in MATLAB bar chart

Tags: matlab, plot, bar-chart

I'm plotting a bar chart of 901 values using MATLAB R2015a:

[image]

What is empty space in the end of plot (black box)? How can I remove it?

Comment: NaNs? Because of division of zeros by zeros?

Comment: No! . There isn't any NaNs in my data!.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Matlab often sets the axes up to a round number (1000 in your case). To change this, you could use:

1. `axes tight`
2. `xlim([0, length(yourplotseries)]`

Answer (score 2):

This behavior can be reproduced e.g. by plotting

```
plot(rand(1,901));
```

MATLAB choses the axis in a way it seems appropriate <sup>[Citation needed]</sup>. It will therefore add white space e.g. in the y axis, above and below the maximum of the signal. As it appears, MATLAB choses to add some space to have an axis from 0 to 1000.

The simplest way to solve this is to use

```
axis tight;
```

which scales the axis such that it fits the minimum and maximum values of the data, as well in x as in y direction, tightly. If you only want to change the x axis limits, use the [`xlim`](http://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/xlim.html) function:

```
xlim([1,901]);
```

Comment: your answer is correct too :-).